# Why are Westworld bullets suddenly deadly?

Tags: westworld-2016

About two episodes or so in to the second season of *Westworld*, bullets magically became deadly to humans. A human gets shot (by Grace) just to verify he was human and not a machine. He was a bit bruised, though if a machine gets shot it's interpreted as much more than a bruise.

So presuming all of the ammunition in the park wasn't magically switched out, how are these same bullets now able to kill humans?

Answer (score 7):

This is explained in an interview with Lisa Joy. The bullets are “smart” [simunitions](https://simunition.com/en/) and when the park goes out of control, they revert to being ordinary rounds.

Comment: Here is a [quote](https://www.slashfilm.com/hbo-westworld-tca-jonah-nolan/) from Christopher Nolan: “It’s not the guns, it’s the bullets. We thought a lot about this. In the original films, the guns won’t operate guest on guest. We felt the guests would want to have a more visceral experience. So when they’re shot, it has an impact. They’re called ‘simmunitions.’ There’s a bit of an impact, a bit of a sting, so it’s not entirely consequence free for the guests.”